# How to work with Git and release via SVN?

Tags: git, svn

**Is there a way to work completely with Git & GitHub and when it comes time to deploy we (force) merge the latest snapshot to an SVN branch?**

Example workflow (repeatable for different branches):

1. Clone Git repo
2. Checkout, branch, make changes, etc.
3. Open pull request to `master`
4. Merge PR
5. Commit to SVN `trunk`

We have experimented with `git-svn` and [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) but they both seem to obfuscate the process and add complexity.

For example, `git-svn` offers `dcommit` which commits based on deltas, but doesn't seem to allow taking the latest snapshot (without commit history) and force-pushing to SVN.  I suppose we could squash the commit history in another branch, but that's an extra step that we'd like to avoid if possible.

Both products also attempt to synchronize changes from SVN, which we don't ever want to do.  It's a one-way street.

We considered the approach of checking out an SVN repo and simply "adding" a Git repo on top (ignoring `.git` and `.svn` respectively) but SVN being folder-based causes problems.  For example, where would the Git repo be `init`'d in the following structure?

```
my-project
  |-- trunk/
  |-- branches/
        |-- integration/
        |-- staging/
        |-- uat/
  |-- tags/
```

We do have an automated build/release process, so any potential solution would ideally be implemented there (as opposed to a manual effort).

Comment: what is the underlying reason for wanting to do it like this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I had the reason in my original question but figured it was adding clutter.  We do lots of work for an enterprise client.  They use an internal SVN server, we like to use Git.  We'd like to keep our Git workflow and simply push to SVN when it's deployment time.  The build server (also hosted by them) would pick up the SVN changes and deploy.  On that note - thanks William Pursell for your condescending, ignorant comment.

Comment: @Terry You can flag comments you do not like so a moderator will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a deep at git reset command if you need one way snapshot git->svn. Basically you can move a state of you master (or other) git branch on top of the git-svn remote without the complexities of merges/rebases. Then you push with git svn dcommit to svn.